# Java Stream over a list and check if the list contains at list one object with one of three given field values

Tags: java, java-stream

Given a class Ball (simplified for this question), where I can not change the `equals` and `hashCode` method

```
class Ball {
    String color;
    //some more fields, getters, setters, equals, hashcode ..
}
```

and a list of balls, I want to return true if the list contains at least one ball for each color value `"RED", "YELLOW" and "GREEN"`. Example inputs:

```
List<Ball> first = List.of(
        new Ball("RED"),
        new Ball("BLUE"),
        new Ball("GREEN"),
        new Ball("RED"),
        new Ball("YELLOW"),
        new Ball("RED"));

List<Ball> second = List.of(
        new Ball("RED"),
        new Ball("BLUE"),
        new Ball("GREEN"),
        new Ball("RED"));
```

expected result for first list is true and for second false. For now I have a classic loop and three counter variables:

```
private static boolean isValidList(final List<Ball> balls) {
    int r = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int g = 0;
    for (Ball ball : balls) {
        String color = ball.getColor();
        if("RED".equals(color)){
            r++;
        }
        else if("YELLOW".equals(color)){
            y++;
        }
        else if("GREEN".equals(color)){
            g++;
        }

        if(r > 0 && y > 0 && g > 0){
            break;
        }
    }
    return r > 0 && y > 0 && g > 0;
}
```

I have tried to refactor it to use streams like below

```
private static boolean isValidListStreams(final List<Ball> balls) {
    long r = balls.stream().filter(ball -> "RED".equals(ball.getColor())).count();
    long y = balls.stream().filter(ball -> "YELLOW".equals(ball.getColor())).count();
    long g = balls.stream().filter(ball -> "GREEN".equals(ball.getColor())).count();
    return r > 0 && y > 0 && g > 0;
}
```

but the above need to stream over the list 3 times. Is there a way I can do it in one go? I can't do it with filter using or

```
return balls.stream()
            .filter(ball -> ball.getColor().equals("RED") ||
                            ball.getColor().equals("YELLOW") || 
                            ball.getColor().equals("GREEN")).count() >= 3;
```

since there may be multiple of the same color.

Comment: The title says `check if the list contains at list one object with one of three given`, however your code checks whether **all given values** are present (*at least the first version, the second has a logical flaw in it*). Can you please resolve this discrepancy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets make it a fair fight, your original snippet is much, much longer than it needs to be:

```java
boolean r = false, y = false, g = false;
  for (Ball ball : balls) {
    String color = ball.getColor();
    if ("RED".equals(color)) r = true;
    if ("YELLOW".equals(color)) y = true;
    if ("GREEN".equals(color)) g = true;
    if (r && y && g) return true;
  }
  return false;
```

Streams don't 'like it' if you have to refer to results of other operations. That's because the stream API tries to cater to way too many scenarios, thus, you get the lowest common denominator. Which, in this case, is parallel processing: Imagine java runs your stream by handing each individual item to a separated out system - now there is no longer such a thing as 'any previous result' or 'have we seen at least 1 red, at least 1 green, and at least 1 yellow ball at this point' - there is no 'this point', there's just the stream itself.

Hence, it's going to either look ugly (because you're using the wrong tool for the job), or, it's fundamentally far more inefficient. It would look something like this:

```
return balls.stream()
  .map(Ball::getColor)
  .filter(x -> x.equals("RED") || x.equals("GREEN") || x.equals("YELLOW"))
  .distinct()
  .count() == 3;
```

Comparing code lengths its not significantly simpler. It is considerably worse in performance: It needs to do a distinct scan which requires another run through, and must iterate the whole thing, whereas the first snippet will stop the moment it sees the third color.

Trying to smash those back in, you're looking at a real ugly mess. Golfed to as small as I could make it:

```
boolean[] c = new boolean[4];
return balls.stream()
  .map(Ball::getColor)
  .peek(x -> c[x.equals("RED") ? 0 : x.equals("YELLOW") ? 1 : x.equals("BLUE") ? 2 : 3] = true)
  .anyMatch(x -> c[0] && c[1] && c[2]);
```

It's not much code but it introduces all sorts of weirdness - it's weird enough that this probably needs commentary to explain what's going on. So not really a 'win'. It certainly isn't going to be any faster than the original.

In general when you are iterating over a collection with the intent to contrast between values and those operations cannot be described in terms of primitives of the list itself (such as `.distinct()` or `.sorted()` or `.limit`) and there is no pre-baked terminal operation (such as `.max()`) that does what you want, it's rather likely you **do not** want streams.

Comment: Wow. So far, the best answer I have received on this platform, with a comprehensible reason and an understandable explanation. Thank you very much. I just don't know which answer to accept now :-). Yours, because it goes beyond what I asked, or the other one, which actually does what I thought it would.

Answer (score 4):

> I can't do it with filter using or since there may be multiple of the same color.

You can just use `distinct` to remove the duplicate colours.

Since you cannot modify `equals`, you should first `map` everything to their color first, then `distinct` and `filter`.

```
return balls.stream()
            .map(Ball::getColor)
            .distinct()
            .filter(color -> color.equals("RED") ||
                             color.equals("YELLOW") || 
                             color.equals("GREEN")).count() == 3;
```

Notice that your original for loop is short-circuiting - once you have found the three required colours, you stop looping. However, `count` will count everything. If that is undesirable, you can do a `limit(3)` before it.

Also, replacing the `||` chain with `Set.of(...).contains` could look better if there are many colours that you want to check:

```
return balls.stream()
            .map(Ball::getColor)
            .distinct()
            .filter(Set.of("RED", "YELLOW", "GREEN")::contains)
            .limit(3)
            .count() == 3;
```

Comment: Works as expected. Thank you very much for the description and the hint with the limit.

Comment: That is a neat way to introduce 'early exit' in sequential streaming modes :) Worth an upvote for that second snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract distinct colors (using Stream API), then simply search in the `Set`.

```java
Set<String> colors = balls.stream().map(Ball::getColor)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
if (colors.contains("RED") && colors.contains("GREEN") && colors.contains("YELLOW")) {
    // test passes  ...
}
```

If required colors are precomputed as a final `Set<String>`, code can be even more readable by using `containsAll` (checking if the retrieved set is a superset of the required set):

```java
final Set<String> requiredColors = Set.of("RED", "GREEN", "YELLOW");
Set<String> colors = balls.stream().map(Ball::getColor)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
if (colors.containsAll(requiredColors)) { /* test passes */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

In sort my suggestions are:

- Don't hard-code values to check against inside the method, provide them as a parameter.
- Use `enum`s, don't rely on strings.

Since you're describing the color of each `Ball` object with a string name (*not for instance as a hex-code*) implies that you expect only a moderate number of colors to be used in your application.

And you can improve the design of the `Ball` class by using a custom `enum` type `Color` instead of stream. It will guard you from making a typo and also provides a possibility to introduce a useful behavior withing the `Color` enum and also benefit from various language and JDK features related to enums.

```
public enum Color {RED, YELLOW, GREEN}
```

And even you don't consider utilizing enums it worth to change the method signature of the method you've listed by including an aditional parameter - a `Set` of colors instead of hard-coding them.

***Note:*** there's also an ***inconsistency*** between the title and the code you've provided. The title says:

> check if the list contains **at list one** object with one of three
> given

However, your code aims checks whether all given values are present.

That's how you can check whether ***at least one color*** from the given set is present, as the question title says,:

```
private static boolean isValidListStreams(final List<Ball> balls, Set<Color> colors) {
    return balls.stream()
        .map(Ball::getColor)
        .anyMatch(colors::contains);
}
```

But if you need to check if ***all*** the ***given colors*** are present, you can do it like that:

```
private static boolean isValidList(final List<Ball> balls, Set<Color> colors) {
    return colors.equals(
      balls.stream()
          .map(Ball::getColor)
          .filter(colors::contains)
          .limit(colors.size())
          .collect(Collectors.toSet())
    );
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Ball> balls = // initializing the source list
    
    isValidListStreams(balls, Set.of(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW)); // or simply EnumSet.allOf(Color.class) when you need all enum elements instead of enumerating them
}
```